# Build Image for emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have Android source code. I make some changes in framework code. Now I want to see my changes in emulator. Can anybody tell me how I can make Image for emulator?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to learn to build Android applications from the beginning.

Try this is [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) from the Android Dev site.

Basically you need the first two lessons - building an app & running your app (which includes running and setting up the emulator).

Comment: is this even related to the question?

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the system.img from the built output and then use this system.img to start the new emulator . Check this [post](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html) to start emulator with your own system image

Answer (score 0):

First setup the environment in linux using the below command :
      source build/envsetup.sh
Then use
        make command to build the source code.
Copy the system.img and ramdisk.img file to your platforms/android-version/image/
Now you can launch the emulator as usual otherwise follow the above suggestion to launch the emulator with current img with out replacing original imgs.